# Need to figure out how to use Git correctly to retrofit old versions of code

Tags: git

We have a large collaborative software development project and are using GitHub for revision control. Several components are being developed in parallel independently. For each component, development currently consists of two parts. First, the code is being modified to improve the main functionality of each component. Second, we discovered that we need to make modifications to the code to add some detailed reporting. The latter change has to be applied retroactively to older versions of the code. I need to figure out the right way to do it using Git. So for example, suppose I need to go back to a commit of May 1 and make the change there, and then apply that change to all commits after that date, making sure that any conflicts with newer version of the code are detected and can be resolved. Is there a definitive guide on how to do it?

Comment: 0_o Why do you think you need to make a retroactive change to all commits? Use the current stable version in production. If you need to move back to a previous production version, then do the rollback, make the changes in a branch, and then merge. Or, better yet, decouple the reporting code from the existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a branch for each old version of your code you want to maintain, and `cherry-pick` the necessary changes onto the branches for old versions.

It's also possible to rebase the change into the git history, but **you don't want to do that**. It will make development difficult for collaborators, as the repository history will change dramatically out from under them, and it misrepresents the real history of your code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with misrepresenting history, especially if it improves testability, and you should be *talking* to your collaborators, in which case there's no particular problem with rewriting their history.

Comment: Rewriting history once it's been made public is generally bad, confusing people and tools and generally frustrating development until everyone can sort things out. Before you've made the history public, however, it's perfectly acceptable (and perhaps recommended). Condensing a topic branch into a single commit prior to merging is fairly reasonable and makes life simpler. In that case, history is absolutely written by the victors (that of course assumes you don't let the bugs win).

Comment: @peachykeen: Right. But, from the sounds of it, what the OP is asking about here would be rewriting history that has been public for over a month. This is generally considered an "antisocial" way of using rebasing.

Comment: @duskwuff That's how I interpret it as well; I'm agreeing with you and disagreeing with hobbs' comment that rewriting public history is ok.